# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to submit a form using curl post method.I have set csrf token properly to the form.

```
<form  action="{{URL::route('the-route')}}"   method="post"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

But it shows `TokenMismatchException` in `VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:`.I am stuck on it using shared hosting, i include my larvel 5 project in `myapp` folder and `laravel public` folder in  `public_html`

As a test I have also tried as some other posts suggested commenting out 
`App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`, in `app/Http/kernal.php` 
to see what would happen. After doing this every time I submit a form I get a message which says redirecting to: `/auth/login` or `/auth/register` depending on where I came from with no success.

Comment: Hey there, can you verify that your tokens match as according to `tokensMatch($request)` in `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` either by using a debugger or dumping the variables using dd()?

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution for me. What you need to do is:

**Go to -> app -> Exceptions -> Handler.php**

and copy and paste this in you render method:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('login')->withErrors('Sorry, your session has expired.     Please login again.');
  }

return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

This will handle the TokenMismatchException for you and display a friendly message on the page :). Hope it helps anyone out there!

Answer (score -1):

```
I just got it working removing the line:

'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'

from /app/Http/Resquests/Kernel.php
```

thank @Mahmoud Nassar

Comment: This isn't good practice, better to find the root of the problem then just remove csrf protection.

Answer (score -1):

**I solved my issue:**

in my case i remove`'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'` from `app/Http/kernal.php` but it's not work but this is best solution of `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46`

i hosted laravel 5 in a shared hosting, As a test I have also tried as some other posts suggested commenting out change my folder structure create a folder in outside `public_html`and add files in that folder then put `public(laravel)` folder in `public_html`  After doing this every time I submit a form I get a message which says redirecting to: /auth/login or /auth/register depending on where I came from with no success.

*so i delete all files and folders include my app and laravel*

last i create laravel 5 in `public_html` and Add following code in .htaccess (if not exist create a .htaccess on laravel root directory)

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

this .htaccess help you to remove `public` from *url*