# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:(Firefox browser) in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i am trying to figure out why this error even though its fresh installation.i got this error in my project so i googled ,none of the answers worked for me.so i created new project and copied all controller ,view, and model.its worked fine after few hours once again token mismatch error.why this happen in laravel ?

my form

```
<form class="form-horizontal action="http://localhost/laravel/public/add-post-new"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-2">Title</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="post_title" placeholder="Title" name="post_title">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-2">Content</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10"><textarea class="form-control" style="resize:none" rows="25" name="post_content"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-2">Featured Image</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10"><input type="file" class="filestyle" data-buttonText="Find" name="featured_image">
            </div>
        </div>
     <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-2">Post Images</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10"><input type="file" class="filestyle"  name="post_gallery[]" multiple />
            </div>
        </div>  

     <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-2">Select Category</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10" >
            <select  class="form-control" name="cat_id">
                <?php $data=Category::all(); ?>
            <option value="0">Default Category</option>
            @foreach($data as $value)
                 <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->cat_name}}</option>
              @endforeach 
        </select>

            </div>
        </div>      
 <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-2">Publish Post</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
           <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="published" id="inlineRadio1" value="1"> Publish 
</label><br>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="published" id="inlineRadio2" value="2"> UnPublish
</label><br>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="published" id="inlineRadio2" value="3"> Draft
</label><br><br>

            </div>
        </div>      
 <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-2">Slider Post</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
           <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="slider_post" id="inlineRadio1" value="1"> Slider Post 
</label><br>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="slider_post" id="inlineRadio2" value="2"> Not required
</label><br><br>


            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Post</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

before asking question i have read many tutorial

[Laravel 5, Forms, TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119951/laravel-5-forms-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-46)

[Laravel 5 Auth Post Submit - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875788/laravel-5-auth-post-submit-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line)

[TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53 in Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934906/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-53-in-laravel-5-1)

[TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661203/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-46)

[Laravel 5, ajax, 500 Internal Server Error, TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460791/laravel-5-ajax-500-internal-server-error-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrf)

[Laravel 5 TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655140/laravel-5-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-46)

[Encountering "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436896/encountering-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-error)

[Laravel TokenMismatchException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427840/laravel-tokenmismatchexception)

http://laravel.io/forum/01-30-2015-laravel5-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken

[TokenMismatchException when uploading a Video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047977/tokenmismatchexception-when-uploading-a-video)

updated:
[image]

Comment: I think the problem could be with the form's action. Try changing it to `{{ url('add-post-new') }}` or something equivalent, instead of `http://localhost/laravel/public/add-post-new`.

Comment: @JohnBupit.i tried not workinng.

Comment: You also don't seem to have `<input name="_token" ... >` in the form. I'm sure it's explained in one of the tutorials you read.

Comment: @JohnBupit.i also tried blade template token that also not working

Comment: Can you post what you tried, and the error you get when you try it?

Comment: @JohnBupit. in question alreadt included my blade template form and instead of that token i have added many stackoverflow user answers but every time run i get same token mismatch error

Comment: I have the same error today, it's working fine on my development env but when I push it to the staging server it throws me this error, I have regenerate the key from artisan, and delete all files in sessions folder in storage with no luck !! it's driving me crazy. I'm using the From:: facade so the hidden input of token is there.

Comment: @tester Did you ever find a solid reason and solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This may help someone.
Check your php files that not start with empty line or space!
It cost me much trouble. Including that above!

Comment: Thanks. I had the same issue and it turned out to be caused by an empty space before the opening <?php tag of the routes.php file.

Comment: Oh lord. I have been googling around for like 1 hour and THIS was the error! A stupid little space in routes.php. I was going crazy here. Thanks a LOT.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this line after opening a form

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token()}}"/>
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>

Comment: except tokenmismatch exception, is everything working fine? and is there any special reason you providing form action like that instead using laravel default action rule? what if you just do /add-post-new in form action? what does it result?

Comment: .working.looks like silly mistake but took long time for me.thank you.is there any reason for that ?

Comment: Well i got into a same problem before and took me a week to solve it. if and only if my answer helps you, help me by marking it as a correct :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86982/discussion-between-sid-and-tester).

Answer (score 1):

Suddenly I am getting this exception.

Then restarting and clean cache works for me.

To clear the cache use :`php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: I was just struggling with this issue and this suggestion resolved the issue for me. It took me an hour to find this so I'm very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

I had this painful error and this is what I did to fix it: 
1. Go to `\Http\Controllers\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php`
2. In the `protected $except` add your route to be excluded from this verification. Example:

```
protected $except = [
        'user*'
    ];
```

3. And if you still get this error, add this function below the protected $except

   ```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

   $regex = '#' . implode('|', $this->except) . '#';

   if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request) || preg_match($regex, $request->path())) {
       return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
   }

   throw new TokenMismatchException;
   ```

   }

And I think that's it. I hope to help someone.

Comment: This is not a good way of fixing it, in fact it's no fix at all. The error shouldnt appear, but this is just a way of saying " Hey let's not check our form at all".